# Parse Json in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, parsing

In my table, the `value` column contains json data. I am using `parsejson` to parse these values. I am using older version of SQL Server. So I am using parsejson:

```
id      fieldid      value
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       70297        {"value":"Billable  ","text":"Billable"}
2       70297        [{"value":"billable","text":"Billable"}]
3       70297        [{"value":"billable","text":"Billable"},
                     {"value":"nonbillable","text":"NonBillable"}]
4       70297        [{"value":"     nonbillable","text":"      NonBillable"}]
```

I need this output:

```
count   stringvalue
--------------------
 3      Billable
 2      nonbillable
```

I am using this query to parse above json values from the table:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + Value 
FROM ValueBindings  
WHERE fieldid = 70297

SELECT COUNT(*), StringValue 
FROM parseJSON(@Names) 
WHERE NAME IN ('value', 'text')  
GROUP BY StringValue

SELECT @Names
```

It is not returning the expected values correctly

Comment: Well, what **is it** returning, and what is the *correct, expected* output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your query like below to get the desired result

```
SELECT COUNT(*), RTRIM(LTRIM(StringValue))
FROM parseJSON(@Names) 
WHERE NAME IN ('value')  
GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(StringValue))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It is Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT([NAME])/2 [COUNT], LTRIM(RTRIM(StringValue)) StringValue
FROM parseJSON(@Names) 
WHERE NAME IN ('value', 'text') AND [NAME] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LTRIM(RTRIM(StringValue))
```

Thanks.